# AWK to extract data from one file with respect to another

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I have an awk script to extract data by pattermatching in one file wrt pattern available in another file.
while running script i am getting some other patterns to, is there any way to update this awk command so that it will look only for exact patterns.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) {print; break}}' /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/test.csv /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/raw/SCCP_ADMIN_FINAL.csv | awk -F"," '{math[($2)]+=$3}END{for (i in math) {print i,math[i]}}'|sort

AINGO 253694944
ARL 67932655
BPL 65466640
CELCO 52181696
CINGU 1147311508
CMM 181063417
CNG 2128485188
CONEC 2434
DNFPM 84467207
ERP 286990079
ETC 45013333
GWLES 111261691
HUM 283010928
IDEAC 143610898
INPHM 210392395
LONES 5
MAN 176941298
MEA 48457597
MONET 335
MOROM 105092112
MOSSL 175407690
ONE 554898379
PTTSA 81164497
RPG 63771906
SPNEP 148860282
TATAS 59847841
TTETC 969
WATAN 187799790
WND 222047363
```

File /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/test.csv:

```
cat /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/test.csv
CNG
WND
HUM
AINGO
IDEAC
MOSSL
INPHM
CMM
MAN
MEA
BPL
ERP
DNFPM
SPNEP
GWLES
ETC
CINGU
ARL
RPG
MOROM
PTTSA
ONE
CELCO
TATAS
WATAN
```

which has 25 names but in above awk output i am getting date for 29, so in result conec, lonec etc are coming extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exact match avoid regex i.e.

Instead of regex match here:

```
if ($0 ~ i)
```

Use equality to compare, like this:

```
if ($0 == i)
```

Comment: I will test your full command with your data file in few minutes when I get back to my computer.

Comment: sure anubhav, i will wait for your reply.
my command is 
grep -F -f /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/raw/25-sccp-raw.csv /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/raw/SCCP_ADMIN_FINAL.csv | awk -F"," '{math[($2)]+=$3}END{for (i in math) {print i,math[i]}}'|sort

Comment: I think you've provided first cvs data here but 2nd csv data is missing. Can you please provide it.

Comment: Anubhav 2nd csv file is really very big, i guess approx 1000 entries are there so its hard to share that with you. you can concider any values for rest o the rows.
Also it woud be good if you provide commands like 
1. it searches data of first csv in second and provides matching date.
1. it searches data of 1st csv in second and provides non matching data.
so the output of 1 st command should be matching patterns and 2nd commands output should be non matching patterns.
Is it possible ? I guess a little change would be required, i am also trying to work on the command shared by you.

Comment: I am sure your command can be simplified. Can you just take 10 records from 1st and 2nd csv and let me know what is your expected output so that I can guide you accordingly.

Comment: here it is
file1

AINGO 253694944

ARL 67932655

BPL 65466640

CELCO 52181696

CINGU 1147311508

CMM 181063417

CNG 2128485188

CONEC 2434

DNFPM 84467207
ERP 286990079
ETC 45013333
GWLES 111261691

Comment: Please provide the file data in your question as comments eat away all new lines.

Comment: here it is
file1

AINGO 253694944
ARL 67932655
BPL 65466640
CELCO 52181696
CINGU 1147311508
CMM 181063417
CNG 2128485188
CONEC 2434
DNFPM 84467207
ERP 286990079
ETC 45013333
GWLES 111261691

---------- file2
...
CNG
WND
HUM
AINGO
IDEAC
MOSSL
INPHM
CMM
MAN
MEA
BPL
ERP
DNFPM
SPNEP
ETC
CINGU

so output should be Data of matching patterns in file 1 wrt file2 and non matching pattern in file 1 wrt file 2.
In short you can see "GWLES" is availalbe in file 1 but not in file 2 so output of first command should not contain contain "GWLES 111261691" while 2nd command's output should show it.

Comment: As you can also see that reading data from comments is very difficult. Please provide the file data in your question (by editing it) as comments eat away all new lines from data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36940/discussion-between-user2043380-and-anubhava)